# Dart - is there a way to prevent adding elements to immutable list at compile time?

Tags: dart, intellij-idea

I am learning Dart.

I have a code like below:

```
void main() {
  someMethod();
}

void someMethod() {
  const List<String> strings = ["First", "Second"];
  strings.add("Third");
}
```

I would like to be forced by the IDE and compiler (for example by the underline in red in the editor) to do such things (so I cannot have exception at runtime)

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: What error do you get? Also, do you mean the error about your list is called `strings` but you are trying to call `add` on `months` which is not defined?

Comment: @julemand101 now I understand that the error is only be thrown at me at runtime. It is `Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list`. So I've updated the question

Comment: What error do you mean? Is it that you are trying to `add` on a `const` defined `List`?

Comment: @julemand101 yes. I guess in the normal language I expect such things to be handled before the runtime

Comment: A `const` defined `List` is still a `List` object seen from a type perspective. So the compiler will just see it as `List` where it is fully valid to call `add`. It is first on runtime, that the `List` is going to read-only. So the analyzer cannot tell you about this issue. Yes, in your example, we can obvious see that it should be able to see the problem. But if you e.g. send the `const List` into a method, we are loosing track of it without having `const` being part of the actual type.

Comment: @julemand101 is there a way in Dart to have immutable list to be known for the compiler? So that those issues are not possible before runtime?

Comment: No, since that would make it incompatible with the `List` interface which are telling us that `List` compatible objects must have a `add` method.

Comment: @julemand101 so what will be better for a use case: fetch list of data from the web, make it immutable and sent to the view layer of my app (so the list cannot be modified further)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by making the `List` immutable? If you have a `List` which is general available, but must not be changed, you could make a method or getter which returns a copy of the `List` for every request of the `List` if you are not trusting the caller to behave correctly. Alternative, you can return a `UnmodifiableListView` (which still is a `List` so no compile check) which might make it more clear what your intension is but will still make a runtime error.

Comment: Alternative solution is to use one of the many packages which provides classes like `IList` which is a immutable list but does not implement the `List` interface. So this kind of list is not really compatible with the rest of the Dart SDK (without converting it back into a `List`) but will make sure that you cannot call e.g. `add` on the returned `IList`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Dart does not support immutable lists at the type system level.

However, some packages provide this:

`built_collection` (which is often used with `built_value`) allows you to create deeply immutable data structures. For example:

```dart
final list = BuiltList([1, 2, 3]);
list.add(4);  // compile time error, there is no add() method
final newList = list.rebuild((b) => b.add(4));

print(list);     // prints [1, 2, 3]
print(newList);  // prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, since `BuiltList` doesn't have an `add` method, it cannot implement `List`. However, if you need to pass it to a function that requires a `List`, you can just use `toList()`.

You also lose the ability to use `const`, but in Flutter (except when dealing with `Widget`s, the performance impact is fairly small.